# Checking if a abstract class has a method that returns a specific string?

Tags: java

I'm relatively new to programming. Lets say I'm looping through an arraylist filled with abstract classes. How would I check if each class had a method "String GetWord()" that returns string "Number".

Comment: I suggest looking into the [Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). It will allow you to do what you want.

Comment: Create an `Interface` wtih `String GetWord()` method and extends all array items from this interfaces.

Comment: Can you explain what you are actually trying to achieve? Checking if a method exists in a object instance isn't really common. Usually you fill a list of a specific type and therefore you know by forehand what methods it has.